# Append block to admin login form

Tags: admin, adminhtml, layout, blocks, event-observer

I need to append a input field to the admin log in page.  I have created an Observer.php hoping to do so.  I simply want to add an input to the login form on the admin side.

app\code\local\Wsu\NewtworkSecurities\Model\Observer.php

```
class Wsu_NewtworkSecurities_Model_Observer extends Mage_Admin_Model_Observer {
    public function appendfeild() {
        echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('wsu_newtworksecurities/newtworksecurities.feildblock')->toHtml();
    }
}
```

app\code\local\Wsu\NewtworkSecurities\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Wsu_NewtworkSecurities>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Wsu_NewtworkSecurities>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <events>
                <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_index_index>
                    <observers>
                        <newtworksecurities>
                            <class>newtworksecurities/observer</class>
                            <method>appendfeild</method>
                        </newtworksecurities>
                    </observers>
                </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_index_index>
            </events>
        </global>
    </config>
```

app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\wsu\newtworksecurities.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <feildblock>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>wsu/newtworksecurities/newtworksecurities.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </feildblock>
    <default>
        <adminhtml_index_login>
            <update handle="feildblock" />
            <reference name="form.additional.info">
                <block type="wsu_newtworksecurities/wsu_newtworksecurities" name="wsu_newtworksecurities">
                    <action method="setFormId"><formId>backend_login</formId></action>
                    <action method="setImgWidth"><width>226</width></action>
                    <action method="setImgHeight"><width>50</width></action>
                </block>
                <block type="wsu_newtworksecurities/feildblock" name="newtworksecurities.feildblock"
                   template="wsu/newtworksecurities/feildblock.phtml" />
            </reference>
        </adminhtml_index_login>
    </default>
</layout>
```

app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\wsu\newtworksecurities\feildblock.phtml

```
<input id="url" type="text" name="<?php echo $this->getfeildblock() ?>" />
```

#### EDIT

So the answer is that it should be the full package_extension class name in the config events node value.  this was the fix, adding the `wsu_` to the class value.  Although @Vicky hit on another try I did, it was not full solution to appending to the login page.  This is what I ended up as

```
        <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_index_login>
            <observers>
                <newtworksecurities>
                    <class>wsu_newtworksecurities/observer</class>
                    <method>appendfeild</method>
                </newtworksecurities>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_index_login>
```

### EDIT 2

Now although it I was able to get to the method I have not been able to get the html from the phtml to show up in the `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>` .  I am expecting that `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\wsu\newtworksecurities\feildblock.phtml` was going to show up but as of yet nothing.  I have read that I may be seeing that that block is being over write it's self,  I have tried to change the events I'm observing with out change.   I'm sure it's hitting my method as I added `echo "TEST!!!!";` and I see it right at the top as expected.  I don't see that block getting the template.

## EDIT 3

It is worth noting that it works for the front end if I just do this, no config event, and use the layout update.  So this is what works on the front.

app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\newtworksecurities.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <feildset>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>wsu/newtworksecurities/newtworksecurities.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </feildset>

    <customer_account_create>
        <update handle="feildset" />
        <reference name="form.additional.info">
            <block type="wsu_newtworksecurities/feildset" name="newtworksecurities.feildset"
                   template="wsu/newtworksecurities/feildset.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </customer_account_create>

    <review_product_list>
        <update handle="feildset" />
        <reference name="product.review.form.fields.before">
                   
            <block type="wsu_newtworksecurities/feildset" name="newtworksecurities.feildset"
                   template="wsu/newtworksecurities/feildset.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </review_product_list>

    <wsu_newtworksecurities_error_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="newtworksecurities.error" template="wsu/newtworksecurities/error.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </wsu_newtworksecurities_error_index>

</layout>
```

app\code\local\Wsu\NewtworkSecurities\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Wsu_NewtworkSecurities>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Wsu_NewtworkSecurities>
        </modules>

        <frontend>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <wsu_newtworksecurities>
                        <file>newtworksecurities.xml</file>
                    </wsu_newtworksecurities>
                </updates>
            </layout>
        </frontend>
    </config>
```

SO this works but I can't get it do work on the login page.  I have added

```
  <admin>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <wsu_newtworksecurities>
          <file>newtworksecurities.xml</file>
        </wsu_newtworksecurities>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </admin>
```

to the config file and in

app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\wsu\newtworksecurities.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <feildset>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>wsu/newtworksecurities/newtworksecurities.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </feildset>

    <adminhtml_index_login>
        <update handle="feildset" />
        <reference name="form.additional.info">
            <block type="wsu_newtworksecurities/feildset" name="newtworksecurities.feildset"
                   template="wsu/newtworksecurities/feildset.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_index_login>

    <wsu_newtworksecurities_error_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="newtworksecurities.error" template="wsu/newtworksecurities/error.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </wsu_newtworksecurities_error_index>

</layout>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the event you're observing is the correct one? I would assume it would have to be controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_index_login. I haven't tested this though.

Comment: I did try that one too and it didn't seem to work.. I base the index_index off the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is that it should not be an observed event.  Here is how I got it to work, in the config.xml I needed to update the `adminhtml` node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Wsu_NewtworkSecurities>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Wsu_NewtworkSecurities>
  </modules>
  <adminhtml>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <wsu_newtworksecurities>
          <file>newtworksecurities.xml</file>
        </wsu_newtworksecurities>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </adminhtml>
</config>
```

and in

app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\wsu\newtworksecurities.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <feildset>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>wsu/newtworksecurities/newtworksecurities.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </feildset>

    <adminhtml_index_login>
        <update handle="feildset" />
        <reference name="form.additional.info">
            <block type="wsu_newtworksecurities/feildset" name="newtworksecurities.feildset"
                   template="wsu/newtworksecurities/feildset.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_index_login>

    <wsu_newtworksecurities_error_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="newtworksecurities.error" template="wsu/newtworksecurities/error.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </wsu_newtworksecurities_error_index>

</layout>
```